# Variable cell width in a div table

Tags: html, css

Here's a link to my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/hr111npf/19/

html:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height:54px; border: 1px solid">
  <div style="display:table; width:100%">
    <div style="display:table-row; width:100%">
      <div id="div1" style="display: table-cell; width 50px; background-color: #c0c0c0;">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Face-kiss.svg/50px-Face-kiss.svg.png"/>      
      </div>
      <div id="div2" style="display: table-cell; width: 100%; background-color: #ffff00; vertical-align: middle; " >
        <div class="caption">This is a long sentence that should get clipped and ellipsis shown</div>
      </div>
      <div id="div3" style="display: table-cell; width: 14px; background-color: #b8eaff; vertical-align: middle">
        <img src="http://reports.tofg.com/i/themes/theme_51/css/blue/images/icons-png/arrow-l-black.png"/> 
      </div>
      <div id="div4" style="display: table-cell; width: 14px; background-color: #ffcccc; vertical-align: middle">
        <img src="https://www.monstermoto.com/img/arrow_red.png"/> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.caption {
    font-size: 1.03em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 230px;
}
```

The width of the outer div must remain fixed at 300px.

I have a div table made up of a single row and 4 columns. The first column has an image that is fixed in width. The last two columns are images that also have fixed width. However the last image on the far right must always be shown, while the image next to it might be shown or hidden. If it's hidden, it must not take up any width space (as though the cell doesn't even exist).

The second column contains text. The length of this text can vary. If the text is too long, ellipsis is shown. If the image in the 3rd column is visible, the width of the text to its left must be shortened. If the image is not visible, the text width needs to grow so that it ends next to the image in the last column.

I haven't been able to successfully get the width of the text to adjust automatically while retaining the ellipsis. Another problem is that the images in the last two columns get pushed outside the table if the text is much larger in size as shown in the example.

Any hints on how to get the second column to automatically adjust its width without causing the images in the last two columns to move or lose the ellipsis?

I can fix this with javascript but am looking for a normal css solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use flexbox for this, it will simplify your html structure and css:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.cell {
  /* this centres the content */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.div2 {
  /* this expands the cell to take all the row's remaining space */
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* add this so the child ellipsis works - weird hack found here - https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/ */
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: #b8eaff;
}

.div4 {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}

.caption {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="div1 cell">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Face-kiss.svg/50px-Face-kiss.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="div2 cell">
    <div class="caption">This is a long sentence that should get clipped and ellipsis shown</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3 cell">
    <img src="http://reports.tofg.com/i/themes/theme_51/css/blue/images/icons-png/arrow-l-black.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="div4 cell">
    <img src="https://www.monstermoto.com/img/arrow_red.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="div1 cell">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a8/Face-kiss.svg/50px-Face-kiss.svg.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="div2 cell">
    <div class="caption">This is a long sentence that should get clipped and ellipsis shown</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3 cell">
  </div>
  <div class="div4 cell">
    <img src="https://www.monstermoto.com/img/arrow_red.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I originally tried a flexbox but couldn't get it to work. Wasn't aware of "flex-grow". Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndroidDev found a solution that avoids the need for absolute positioning - and simplifies css a bit more - see edit above, basically instead of absolute positioning, you can add min-width onto the cell

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the caption, should fix it:

```
.caption {
    max-width: 222px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Edit:** Here's an alternative solution with the *table layout* which allows the 3rd column to be hidden and the 2nd column expand automatically:

Firstly, For caption, don't set `max-width`, and keep `width` set as `auto` (no width).

```
.caption {
    font-size: 1.03em;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 5px; 
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*max-width: 230px;*/
}
```

Secondly, For 2nd column `div2`, keep `width` set as `auto` (no width).

Finally, add `table-layout: fixed;` for the table.

By the way, `div1`'s width `width 50px;` is missing the colon (:).

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hr111npf/21/). Now if you add `display: none` or delete the 3rd column, the 2nd column will expand.

Comment: I tried this out but if you hide the image in the 3rd column, the text doesn't grow in width, which is what I want.

Comment: @AndroidDev Updated my question, with this answer, you still use the table-layout where you don't need to re-write the entire HTML.